# PHP Select statement with conditions

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I am new in android and PHP, how to get data from database when we know only single data will return, I already have my php code and android project, but in my php return using array I want to return only one data not in array because I know only one data will be selected and I want to get the value in my android project using retrofit, here is my code

search.php

```
<?php  require_once('config.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM pelanggan where email LIKE '%$email%' ";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,array('id_pel'=>$row[0],'id_role'=>$row[1],'email'=>$row[2],'nama'=>$row[3],'no_identitas'=>$row[4],'telp'=>$row[5],'alamat'=>$row[6]));
}
echo json_encode(array("value"=>1,"result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);}?>
```

Register.java

```
    public Pelanggan getPelangganByEmail(String email){
    List<Pelanggan> myList=new ArrayList<>();
    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RegisterAPI api=retrofit.create(RegisterAPI.class);
    Call<Value> call=api.searchPelanggan(email);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Value>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
            //what I should do in this statement
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Value> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is a PHP question or Java? Sounds like you are asking about the how to handle the PHP return in the java. Your PHP is open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

It better to create REST server than response `JSON` just in body of `HTTP` . But for your case, to send single object of `JSON` instead of be in array . Encode simple `object` of PHP instead of encode `array` .

```
<?php  require_once('config.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM pelanggan where email LIKE '%$email%' ";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)

$myObj->id_pel = $row[0];
$myObj->id_role = $row[1];
$myObj->email = $row[2];
.................

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;

mysqli_close($con);}?>
```